# Why WHERE filter is changing sorting?

Tags: sqlite

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT sort,sku,brand_name,max_price,name,price,special_price,max_sav_perc,max_special_price,url,category_url,product_count 
FROM product_sort ps  
LEFT JOIN products p  
LEFT JOIN categories c  
ON ps.product_id =  p.sku 
AND p.category_url =  c.api_url 
WHERE sort =0  
AND category_url ='category-name' 
LIMIT 72 OFFSET 0
```

If I remove

```
AND category_url ='category-name'
```

it works correctly, the result has the same ordering as the entries in product_sort and products. But if I let it there I get completly different sorting (don't even understand after what is sorting). The returned entries / entries count are the same in both cases, just ordering is different.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify an order.

The DB returns the records in the fastest order (means unordered) if you don't specify a specific one.

Add the column you want to order by before the `limit`

```
order by some_column asc
```

Comment: Is there any way I can tell the database to return just in insertion order without doing `ORDER BY ID`?

Comment: No. The DB does not store the inserting order internally